# How to Round() in Linq to SQL query?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, rounding

In a LINQ To SQL query, how can I apply a Round function on a column in my output?

My query is

```
  From s In oRecelDB.Items Where s.BIN = 'ABC' Select s.ITEMNMBR, s.QUANTITY
```

and the results are

```
ITEM I   35.0000
ITEM 2   45.0000
ITEM 3   23.0000
```

I want to remove the .00000 from the Second column value. How to do that in my query?

Comment: Do you want to round the number or just drop the decimal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply convert the value to an Integer:

```
From s in oRecelDB.Items Where s.BIN = 'ABC' _
    Select s.ITEMNMBR, Quantity = System.Convert.ToInt32(s.QUANTITY)
```

Comment: Is this the C# form  ? Can i have the vb.net equivalent ?

Comment: @Shyju - That should be the VB.NET form.

Comment: I tried that & i am getting an error "Range variable name can be inferred only from a single or qualified name with no arguments" . Any idea why ?

Comment: @Shyju - I just updated. I forgot to give a name to the result of the conversion. You should be good to go now.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to simply drop the decimal values use [`Math.Floor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7ycc7xh.aspx):

```
From s In oRecelDB.Items Where s.BIN = 'ABC' _
  Select s.ITEMNMBR, Math.Floor(s.QUANTITY)
```

It'll return you a decimal datatype. That may/not be what you want.